# cURL error (6) Could not resolve host: api.fda.gov

Tags: curl

I am trying to generate a code that will extract from the openFDA API through the Command Prompt, but something isn't working with cURL. My overall code is this:

```
FOR /L %i IN (0,100,500) DO echo curl -glob "api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?&search=receivedate:[20040101+TO+20150101]&limit=100&skip=%i"
```

But on an even more basic note, I am having issues with cURL when I type:

```
curl -glob "api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?&search=receivedate:[20040101+TO+20150101]&limit=100"
```

because it always results in "rl (6) Could not resolve host: api.fda.gov" Is there any way past this error?
I will also take any suggestions on my initial code if anyone has anything.

Comment: Please note that it is an SSL connection with a redirect from none-SSL to SSL.

Comment: 'Could not resolve host' suggests that the curl application and, by association, your computer/OS, could not look up the host 'api.fda.gov'. You may wish to confirm this via nslookup and look at fixing any name resolution issues your computer may have.

Comment: @JasonMusgrove  I think it has something to do with openSSL or a proxy setting or something, but I don't know how to fix those. I have tried other websites and even checked my url and it should produce some sort of output but it doesn't